# How do I properly communicate with child processes using IPC?

Tags: c, ipc

I'm trying to create several child processes that will handle 'commands' from the parent and return the results. For this, I'm using and keeping track of pipes for each process.

However, I cannot seem to get them working properly. Here's a small snippet for 1 parent and 1 child. I get "abc" as the second payload instead of "xyz123".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  int cmd_pipe[2];
  int msg_pipe[2];
  int len_pipe[2];
  if (pipe(cmd_pipe) < 0) {
    printf("\nCMD Pipe error!\n");
  };
  if (pipe(msg_pipe) < 0) {
    printf("\nMSG Pipe error!\n");
  };
  if (pipe(len_pipe) < 0) {
    printf("\nLEN Pipe error!\n");
  };
  if (fork() == 0) {
    // child
    int command;
    char buffer[10];
    while(1) {
      printf("\nChild process waiting for command.\n");
      read(cmd_pipe[0], &command, sizeof(command)); // will block until it gets something
      if (command == 5) {
        char* payload1 = "abc";
        size_t payload1_len = strlen(payload1);
        write(len_pipe[1], &payload1_len, sizeof(payload1_len));
        write(msg_pipe[1], payload1, payload1_len);
      }
      if (command == 2) {
        char* payload2 = "xyz123";
        size_t payload2_len = strlen(payload2);
        write(len_pipe[1], &payload2_len, sizeof(payload2_len));
        write(msg_pipe[1], payload2, payload2_len);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // parent
    sleep(2); // wait for child
    int cmd = 5;
    printf("\nSending command %d to child\n", cmd);
    write(cmd_pipe[1], &cmd, sizeof(cmd));
    int length;
    read(len_pipe[0], &length, sizeof(length)); // length of payload
    char payload[length];
    read(msg_pipe[0], payload, length);
    printf("\nGot payload: %s\n", payload); // %s would be "abc" here.

    cmd = 2;
    printf("\nSending command %d to child\n", cmd);
    write(cmd_pipe[1], &cmd, sizeof(cmd));
    read(len_pipe[0], &length, sizeof(length)); // length of payload
    char payload2[length];
    read(msg_pipe[0], payload2, length);
    printf("\nGot second payload: %s\n", payload2); // %s should be "xyz123" here but it's still abc
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a single pipe for both directions. But then, there's a serious error here: `read(fds[0], payload, length);` <- `payload` is just an uninitialized pointer, it's **not** pointing to usable memory. Try `malloc(length)` or use a variable-length array like `char payload[length];` after you read your length.

Comment: This is wrong as well: `printf("\nGot payload: %s\n", *payload);` -- dereferencing `payload` yields a `char` (single character).

Comment: If it is just about ordinary C strings - these are nullterminated so you don't need the length to be passed (`len = strlen(...) + 1`) - sure, if this is just demo data and internall nulls are possible, you need the length (or you could do [COBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Overhead_Byte_Stuffing) alternatively...).

Comment: @Aconcagua you still might want to know in advance how many characters you should try to `read()` from your pipe.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for that. So it works if I use different  pipes for length, payload etc. So I can't reuse pipes?

Comment: A pipe is unidirectional. Of course you can "reuse" it, but you should better use a pair of pipes, one for the direction child->parent and one for the opposite.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh okay. I can't seem to reuse the pipe though. Take a look at the last portion of my updated code snippet.